What is causing a "Orhpaned" entry in my list of Open With programs for PDF on a Windows 2019 Server?
Problem:
I manage some Windows 2019 servers that deploy an application to end-users. The application they run has a feature that does a Shell Execute command to open the User's Windows default PDF viewer embedded inside the application (for PDF Previews). For about a year we were using FoxIt PDF Reader as the default, and after a recent update they released, we opted to go back to Adobe Acrobat Reader that we always used prior. While some of the 30 servers have Adobe working fine, a few have a strange issue where they can't seem to launch any default PDF viewer after the change.
In removing FoxIt and re-installing Adobe, we seem to have created some kind of registry issue which is now preventing the the application from being able to do shell execute to launch the default PDF Viewer. The application itself did not update or change. Windows updates were applied at the time server restarted (between Foxit Removal and Adobe reinstall).
What I've Been Looking At
No matter what we set the default PDF viewer to for the user, the application refuses to launch it. The reason I think it is a registry problem is this:

I started with the basics like reboot, uninstall Adobe Reader, reinstall, reboot again.
I found a FoxIt "cleanup" tool that I tried, since apparently it has a reputation for leaving a mess behind. No change.
I can't seem to figure out where this "Other Option" is coming from that looks blank, so I backed up the registry and ran CCleaner. It looks wrong, which is why I latched onto it thinking it might be the root cause of my issue. CCleaner did remove a lot of references to FoxIt, but the issue was not resolved.
Next I started looking around Stack and found some similar posts, which lead me into combing the registry locations with respect to PDF file types.
This one was helpful, but I still don't know what to delete or cleanup to address the issue at hand.
https://superuser.com/questions/266268/where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-file
This is what my registry looks like on one of the affected servers:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.PDF\OpenWithList




Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf


Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\OpenWithProgIds


Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf


Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf


Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf


TL;DR
So, what might be causing my orphaned reference to an older Adobe install location in my Open With options? Alternatively, if you think I should be looking elsewhere for the cause of my problem, I'm open to suggestions.

why, not just set by application the defaults? it will speed it up instead waiting for the internet for a response

I might not be understanding your question, but if you are asking why I don't simply just pick a new default, It's because doing so says it is default, but the 3rd party app looking to launch my default cannot find it. Devs of the app think server issue since the app didn't change, and not all servers in the same environment exhibit the same behavior.

nearly, you can set standard apps either by ending protocol or by application. and if you use the last one, then you can reset all at once by using ms-settings:defaultapps 

The question is really about an application failing to run another application, Adobe Reader. You should run ProcMon to identify the offending registry values that the application is using that is causing what you are attempting to do that is not working. You should also consider using Remote Desktop application installation procedures and validation. It is 100% not like a desktop, and there will be plenty of other scenarios like this in the future.
